# How can I get my landlord to improve my apartments heating efficiency?

Tags: electricity, heating, usa, renting

I am renting a unit in an older building that has a lot of gaps in the doors and windows and poor insulation in the walls. Is there a way to make the landlord fix this? Some sort of property codes or something? Is it wrong to think that it’s the Landlord’s responsibility to upkeep various aspects of the house to improve its heating efficiency? I'm living in Cincinnati Ohio.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Sustainable Living! We've had a similar question on this site: [How can I get my landlord to install better insulation?](http://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/306/how-can-i-get-my-landlord-to-install-better-insulation/307) Maybe some of the answers there are relevant to your question as well. Please feel free to revise your question if there are still points not addressed in the answers.

Comment: Earthliŋ is right. As it is both questions are exactly the same. If you edit this question to ask for clarifications that are not discussed in the other question, we will re-open this question.